# Inserting a new key-value pair to all objects in an array of objects without looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I have an array of objects containing objects with similar structure. I need to add a new key value pair to all the objects in the array. How can I do it **without looping** the entire array.

Providing an example of the output that I require,

```
let arr = [{a:1,b:2}, {a:2,b:3}];
let key = c;
let value = 3;
```

Required output will be like,

```
//arr2 = [ {a:1,b:2,c:3}, {a:2,b:3,c:3}]
```

P.S: Tried using spread operator with little or no success.

Comment: *How can I do it without looping the entire array.* Why do you have a requirement of **no looping**?

Comment: `arr[0].c = el.c; arr[1].c ...`

Comment: @Teemu You'll still loop for all the indices, right?

Comment: @Yash Nope, I hardcode them to my file = ).

Comment: @DanPhilip Can you please shed some light on this "no loop" thing? Why should you do things without proper tools?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The whole 'no-loop' policy is just to reduce overheads as I have to loop a huge array. Just checking if its possible.

Comment: FWIW, spread notation (it's not an operator) is not applicable to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Yash Hardly ... But I've to, since I've that stupid restriction.

Comment: This added object, should it then, after adding, behave independently? If not, just keep a collection of shared objects?!

Comment: @DanPhilip If you are worried about complexity, it won't matter if you use a loop. Since you've to add a property to each of the object in the array, you've to at least visit the each one of them, making  the complexity O(input). A simple `for` loop will be of same complexity.

Comment: When you say loop, do you only mean in terms of a looping construct like while & for... or is Array.each, ok?.  It's still a loop, but the loop construct has just been done for you.  If so then it's as simple as `arr.forEach(e=>e.c=3)`

Comment: @Yoshi I just want the key and value to be added to each object of the array.

Comment: @Keith I was hoping to go with no loop at all, like a single point of access to all elements of the array.

Comment: I see, still, you could use a collection of *shared features* to look for undefined properties on first access.

Comment: @DanPhilip: *"The whole 'no-loop' policy is just to reduce overheads as I have to loop a huge array. Just checking if its possible."* Ah. :-) Nope, it isn't. (Don't do the `Object.prototype` thing, I was being facetious there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do it without looping the entire array.

You can't (reasonably). The *completely unreasonable* way would be to add it to `Object.prototype`, which is inherited by all objects, and thus would add it to all objects in the array — and everywhere else.

But again: You can't reasonably, you need to loop (in one form or another). That loop might be recursion a'la functional programming, but it's basically still a loop.

Here's the recursive technically-not-a-loop way:

```js
let arr = [{a:1,b:2}, {a:2,b:3}];
let el  = {c:3};
(function go(a, i, e) {
    if (i < a.length) {
        a[i].c = e.c;
        go(a, i + 1, e);
    }
})(arr, 0, el);
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about adding a key value to the object prototype.

Comment: @DanPhilip  You would just do `Object.prototype.c = 3`  But that's not a good idea at all, but you could inherit from object, and then add to the inherited prototype.  But then your array construct wouldn't look the same.

Comment: @DanPhilip: You **really, really, really don't want to do that**. But if you did, you wouldn't want to do it the way Keith showed. Instead: `Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "c", {value: el.c});` (so it's non-enumerable). But you **really, really, really don't want to do that**. :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use **map()** operator on array and **Object.assign()** to append the key, value pair

```js
 let arr = [{a:1,b:2}, {a:2,b:3}];
 let finalArray = arr.map(function(obj){return Object.assign(obj,{c:3});})
console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: @PraveenKumarD But `.map()` is going to loop over the array. And OP wants a solution without the loop.